# acts_as_list problem with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The problem I have is at the bottom.

Models:

```
class Skill
  has_many :tags  
  acts_as_list :column => 'sequence'
end

class Tag
  belongs_to :skill 
  acts_as_list :column => 'sequence', :scope => :skill
end
```

View:

```
<table id="skills">

  <% @skills.each do |s| %>
    <tr id="skill_<%= s.id %>">

      <td>
        <%= s.name %>
      </td>

      <td>
        <ul id="tags">
        <% s.tags.each do |t| %>
          <li id="tag_<%= t.id %>">
            <%= t.name %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </td>

    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

jQuery for drag and drop:

```
$( "#skills" ).sortable({          
  axis: 'y',
  dropOnEmpty: false,
  handle: '.handle',
  cursor: 'move',
  items: 'tr',
  opacity: 0.4,
  scroll: true,
  update: function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#skills').sortable('serialize') + "&authenticity_token=" + "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
      dataType: 'script',
      complete: function(request){
        $('#skills').effect('highlight');
      },
      url: '<%= url_for :action => 'sort', :controller => 'skills' %>'
    })
  }
});

$( "#tags" ).sortable({          
  axis: 'y',
  dropOnEmpty: false,
  handle: '.handle',
  cursor: 'move',
  items: 'li',
  opacity: 0.4,
  scroll: true,
  update: function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: $('#tags').sortable('serialize') + "&authenticity_token=" + "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
      dataType: 'script',
      complete: function(request){
        $('#tags').effect('highlight');
      },
      url: '<%= url_for :action => 'sort', :controller => 'tags' %>'
    })
  }
});
```

Controller for Tags:

```
def sort
  @tags = Tag.all
  @tags.each do |tag|
    tag.sequence = params['tag'].index(tag.id.to_s) + 1
    tag.save
  end
  render :nothing => true
end
```

---

**PROBLEM:**

After dragging the tags there is an error:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+):
  app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:12:in `block in sort'
  app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:11:in `each'
  app/controllers/tags_controller.rb:11:in `sort'
```

I found the error is gone if I load tags belonging to a specific Skill like this:

```
def sort
  @tags = Skill.find(1).tags
```

**Question** - how to tell the controller which tags to load (but not all tags)?

---

**A SOLUTION I FOUND...**

Tags controller:

```
def sort
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:tag]).first
  @skill = Skill.find_by_id(@tag.skill_id)
  @tags = @skill.tags
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error occurred while evaluating nil.+):

This means that whatever `params['tag'].index(tag.id.to_s) + 1` (from sort in controller) is supposed to do is actually resulting in `nil + 1`.

If your solution performs as expected, then I don't see a problem with it.

As a tip, `@skill = Skill.find_by_id(@tag.skill_id)` could be shortened to `@skill = @tag.skill` if you do `belongs_to :skill` in your Tag model.